# Using the STELLAR LABORATORY (HORIZON) UI to interface/connect to a LOCALHOST Standalone STELLAR core network

Tags: stellar-core

I am new to the Stellar network and would like to TEST Stellar's capabilities - via a standalone implementation (http://localhost:8000) of the 'STELLAR/QUICKSTART' on my MAC laptop.

The installation is up and running which reports that the HORIZON API (as per the Stellar Laboratory), POSTGRES & STELLAR CORE are available with NO ERRORS.

However, I cannot get the HORIZON UI (http://localhost:8000) to connect with the Stellar Core - to allow me to create an ACCOUNT and persist the details on my standalone Stellar implementation.

Has anyone done this successfully before, and what should I do/change to get it to work ?? Many Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I do this routinely as part of a test suite. Exactly what errors do you see that convinces you Horizon can't communicate with Core?

Comment: Did you follow the quickstart instructions? https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/quickstart.md